# What is the alternative to HtablePool for pooling tables in Hbase

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I am going through many examples and blogs for hbase connection pooling.

I tried using Htablepool which the compiler shows its depreciated (using cloudera cdh 5.4.0, Hbase version - 1.0.0-cdh5.4.0)

And also Htable class is not Thread safe so instead of directly instantiating Htable i am trying to use HtableInterface by getting a connection from HConnectionManager but this is also depreciated.

It says to use ConnectionFactory.

Please can i get a complete optimised and best way to do connection pooling with having pools of tables  Alternate to HTablePool

Answer (score -1):

Even Hconnectionmanager is now deprecated. New way is to use ConnectionFactory.

I was also puzzled to to find no connectionpooling in new client as compared to HTablePool in old APIs. But the new way is to pass executor service to ConnectionFactory.createConnection in the 2nd param. Look at this code for more reference
https://hbase.apache.org/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/example/MultiThreadedClientExample.html

If you do not pass the executor service, it creates a default pool which will eventually as many threads as the number of region servers.

I did a perf test to see how passing different sized executor service does against not explicitly passing any executor service and believe me the default method (not passing executor service) did as good as passing service with thread pool more than 20 in my case ( i had 10 region server).
So in my opinion, you can use it without passing executor service explicitly.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.